# Dynamically add image to table layout

Tags: android, tablelayout

Is there a way to dynamically add an image to the table layout? Furthermore, is there a way to add several images into different parts of that table layout dynamically?

Edit: per below, i'd like to be able to click and switch the images inside the table layout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to create a grid out of images, take a look at [Grid View](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-gridview.html).

Comment: yes I've seen that, but I'd like to make the images clickable, then swap the images.

Comment: You can make the images clickable - and swap the images using a Grid View. You could create some kind of custom adapter to it.